# Impossible to connect to Google services after rename package

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm facing an strange problem with Google Play Games Services. I had a game using this service published as alpha and all was working. Now I uploaded the same game but with a different package name and the same certificate. I've relinked the app and I deleted the old Client ID. The new one is using the correct package name. I also added my email address as an alpha tester. With all of this, Google Play Games Services doesn't work. I get this message on sign in:

The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.

What am I forgetting?

Comment: You did create a new client id for the new version and changed all mentions of that id in your app?

Comment: The id of the app has not changed (the numbers). Indeed, all the linked apps share the same id.